# Robocopy to copy each source subfolder to different destination folder

Tags: robocopy, directory, copying

I have a folder structure like this:

Source

```
C:\Data
        Data1_timestamp
        Data2_timestamp
        Data3_timestamp
        Data4_timestamp
```

Destination

```
D:\Data
        Data1
        Data2
        Data3
        Data4
```

Is it possible to use robocopy to copy each source subfolder to the corresponding destination subfolder (eg. Data1_timestamp would be copied to  Data1, Data2_timestamp to Data2 etc)

Destination after the copy

```
D:\Data
        Data1\Data1_timestamp
        Data2\Data2_timestamp
        Data3\Data3_timestamp
        Data4\Data4_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you could carry this out with a combination of a **for** command and robocopy.  Plus a bit of a substring operation using **%MYVAR:~0,5%**

Comment: I was afraid of that. Also thanks for the suggestion, but my second choice will be VBScript or PowerShell. Thanks again.

Comment: Powershell will eat this up.

Comment: Here is my first draft: gci c:\Data | %{copy $_.FullName "d:\Data\$($_.Name.Split((`"_`"),2)[0])"}